Is this "leak" expected from a brand new sump pump?
I recently purchased a 1/3 HP everbilt sump pump from home depot and noticed it was leaking from the side, so I exchanged it for another one, thinking it was faulty.
The second one has the same leak.
You can see the leak in the bottom left of the image, or better in the video in the link below.
It seems like this should not be the case, but I just want to be sure before I return the second one.
Additional images including a video: https://imgur.com/a/GtmWtEu


Is it leaking from the seam or is there a made hole?

Looks like it's missing a gasket or O-ring at the joint between upper and lower. The same problem could afflict the entire production lot. If you exchange this one, see if you can find an old dusty box in the back of the shelf; it might be a different production lot.

This is one of those read-the-manual moments.
"This pump uses an air evacuation method called a "weep hole".  The weep hole allows air to escape the pump casting to prevent air lock.  When the water is pumped down to a low level, some water may stream out of the weep hole."

+1 RTFM (read the fine manual).

This seems to be leaking from the seam, not anything that I would naturally classify as a "hole". How can I verify that this is water streaming out of the weep hole? I'm worried this might just be a pump (or technically two) leaking at the seams because it was dropped one too many times.

The impeller and several other parts are user-serviceable so the curious minded owner would be welcome to remove those parts and inspect them.
